# Android Studio native breakpoints not being hit

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-ndk

I have a large Android project with lots of native and Java code. The Java code debugs fine. All breakpoints are being hit.

The native debugger connects, but breakpoints are never hit. I am using ndk-build.

In my gradle file I have declared the following:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        packagingOptions{
            doNotStrip "*/armeabi-v7a/*.so"
            doNotStrip "*/arm64-v8a/*.so"
            doNotStrip "*/x86/*.so"
            doNotStrip "*/x86_64/*.so"
        }
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

Where I have declared my native function in Java, they show up red with the error "Cannot Resolve Corresponding JNI Function"

I have followed every step of this post:
[" Cannot Resolve Corresponding JNI Function" Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914167/cannot-resolve-corresponding-jni-function-android-studio)

The project builds and runs fine, yet the native functions are not recognized in Java.

One thing I noticed is that there is no armeabi-v7a folder in `obj\local\`

But there are armeabi-v7a folders in

```
build\intermediates\transforms\stripDebugSymbol\release\0\lib
build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\release\0\lib
build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\obj\local
build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\obj\local
.externalNativeBuild\ndkBuild\release
.externalNativeBuild\ndkBuild\debug
```

Are there any other obscure settings that might disable native debugging?

EDIT:

This is how I declare my native functions in Java (BaseActivity.java):

```
native boolean SetupProject ();
```

This is how I declare them in C++:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_mycompany_myapp_BaseActivity_SetupProject(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
    //some code
    return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

EDIT2:

Library load:

```
static {
    try { 
        System.loadLibrary("myapp");                                                        
    } catch( UnsatisfiedLinkError e ) {
         Log.e("MyApp", "Native code library failed to load: " + e);
     }
}
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := myapp

FILE_LIST_APP := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/App/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(FILE_LIST_APP:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/App

LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS := true
APP_SHORT_COMMANDS := true

LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -O0 -Wno-error -fshort-wchar -fpermissive -g -ggdb -ffast-math

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics -ldl
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -ldl
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -lz
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-25
APP_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=format-security

APP_OPTIM   :=   debug

APP_STL     := gnustl_static
```